# Glide generates ImageView with size 0

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am building a simple Android app using Glide. The feature is simple: the app sends a network request and gets back a list of image URLs. Then using Glide and RecyclerView, I want to display the images.

The way I wish to display the images is that they should fill the width of the screen, and the height should just auto adjusted to maintain the original aspect ratio.

Here is the layout of the view holder of my RecyclerView:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the code of my view holder:

```kotlin
class PhotoViewHolder(private val binding: PhotoViewHolderBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(imageUrl: String?) {
        if (imageUrl != null) {
            Glide.with(binding.imageView).load(imageUrl).into(binding.imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

What happens, however, is that I cannot see anything on my screen. Using the Layout Inspector, I found that the ImageViews are there, they are just of 0 height and 0 width:

[image: Screenshot of the Layout Inspector]

I wonder why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change the Glide code into this:

```kotlin
            Glide.with(binding.root.context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
                })
```

Then it works. So apparently it has to use a `CustomTarget`. I still don't understand why.